# How do I efficiently pull up the most recently edited .TXT files?

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-search

Using Windows is there a command-line string I can execute to show the most recently edited notepad files?

Many times, I don't know the name of the file I need... but I know that I edited it within the last 3 days. What's an efficient way I can perform such an operation in Windows?

Comment: Editor's history must show the names of the files edited last.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT -  they may exist in subfolders as well

Comment: @Akina -  ok I see,  so perhaps Notepad doesn't show the names of those files ?

Comment: On Windows 10 Right-Click on the Notepad icon on QuickLaunch pane shows last edited files list. Or you may use alternative text editor - for example, NPP may remember up to 99 last files.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - This gave me an error :   _.Split : The term '_.Split' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:8
+ $z| % {_.Split(",")[1]};
+        ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (_.Split:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT -  I'll play with this code , I see what ur trying to do

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT  -  its  5.1.18362.145

Answer (score 3):

## Easily get the most recent modified files recursively in order

> **One way to do this with PowerShell would be to...**
>
> 1. Use [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html) to get a recursive list of files `.txt` extensions
> 2. Pipe that through to a [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html) loop and use
>      [grouping and subexpression
>      operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) to return the
>      `LastWriteTime` property value followed by a comma and the full
>      path file name of each file—sort that in descending order by the
>      `LastWriteTime` value.
> 3. With the **#1** and **#2** result being a variable, pipe that over in a loop to [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html), with the comma
>      being the delimiter, and return only the 2nd index (i.e. `[1]`) of the
>      iterated value and retain the descending order of the time stamp but return only the full path file names.

### PowerShell

```
$Src = "C:\YourFolder";
$z = (Get-Childitem -Path $Src -include "*.txt" -File -Recurse | % {"$($_.LastWriteTime), $($_.FullName)"}) | Sort-Object -Descending;
$z | % {$_.Split(",")[1]};
```

---

#### Example Structure

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\A
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\B
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\Test.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\Test2.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\Test3.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\A\2019-07-29 22_18_52-Inquiries.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\A\blah.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\A\Test4.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\B\FLLtest.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\B\FLLtest2.txt
```

#### Example Command Output (with date time)

```
PS C:\Users\user> (Get-Childitem -Path $Src -include "*.txt" -File -Recurse | % {"$($_.LastWriteTime), $($_.FullName)"}) | Sort-Object -Descending;
12/09/2019 18:14:09, C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\A\Test4.txt
12/08/2019 20:27:26, C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\Test2.txt
12/03/2019 23:55:50, C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\Test3.txt
11/02/2019 12:51:35, C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\B\FLLtest2.txt
11/02/2019 12:49:09, C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\B\FLLtest.txt
07/29/2019 22:38:33, C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\A\blah.txt
07/29/2019 22:38:17, C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\A\2019-07-29 22_18_52-Inquiries.txt
06/21/2019 23:38:01, C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\Test.txt
```

#### Example Full Script Output

```
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\A\Test4.txt
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\Test2.txt
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\Test3.txt
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\B\FLLtest2.txt
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\B\FLLtest.txt
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\A\blah.txt
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\A\2019-07-29 22_18_52-Inquiries.txt
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dir\Test.txt
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Sort-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/sort-object.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

Comment: Getting the `TOP x` records or getting more granular or specific is just a trivial matter so, if you have questions, just let me know as a potential adjustment is simply enough.

Answer (score 0):

---

This is simple option to do this in **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)** or command line for local/folder list only:

---

```bat
/o:d = order by date (old first) || is the same /od
/o-d = order by date (reverse -) || is the same /o:-d
/b   = basic out put (name only) 
/s   = recursively

:: - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ::

rem./  you can use any options...

dir /o:-d /b /s
dir /o-d /b /s 
dir /o-d/b/s
dir/o-d/b/s
```

---